# Independent Column sizes in Scene2D Table in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

For my game's (mostly GUI based) UI i am using table from Scene2D in libGDX. I want independent column sizes in my table but first cell width is the width for all other rows in column. Is it possible to have a table in Scene2D with independent cell width in each row? For example, first cell in first row should have 10% width and first cell in second row should have 15% width.
I tried using Horizontal Groups, Containers but they make my code too shabby and cluttered.[image]

Comment: Hey, did you find out how to do this? I'm kind of having the exact problem.

Comment: i had to insert table within table. In whichever row you need different column size, insert a table of size 1 x N (N=no. of columns). I hope i am clear.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yBLDNvG2

Answer (score 4):

There is an option to do this:

First of all you need to find out what your smallest size of a column is, therefore you have to merge all rows into one and pick the smallest width of all columns.

[image: merging rows]
the numbers in the picture are displaying the width of the columns.

Knowing your smallest width (in my example it's displayed as 1) allows you to create a table with as many columns as you need. (for my example its 17 columns -> width / 17).

Now use:

```
table.add(Actor).colspan(#); //replace # with the amount of columns you want to span
```

In my example this would be:

```
Table t = new Table(skin);
t.add(Actor0).colspan(1).expandX();
t.add(Actor1).colspan(5).expandX();
t.add(Actor2).colspan(3).expandX();
t.add(Actor3).colspan(3).expandX();
t.add(Actor4).colspan(2).expandX();
t.add(Actor5).colspan(3).expandX().row();
t.add(Actor6).colspan(2).expandX();
t.add(Actor7).colspan(2).expandX();
t.add(Actor8).colspan(5).expandX();
t.add(Actor9).colspan(4).expandX();
t.add(Actor10).colspan(3).expandX();
t.add(Actor11).colspan(1).expandX();
```

output looks as follows: (note that I added a row with equally sized columns for reference above)
[image: output]